# how to plot using time as the xlabel in R

Tags: r, time, plot

data format:

4/15/13 8:59    0.56525

4/15/13 9:00    0.8123

I wanna use the second and third columns to plot a graph in R, as xlabel and ylabel,respectively.

Thx.

Comment: Do you want to plot time vs the data ? You don't want to plot the year. You only want to plot time and data. Is that right ?

Comment: sure thanks     just plot time and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code and see if it meets your requirement.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
sample <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "4/15/2013", class = "factor"), 
               Time = structure(1:2, .Label = c("8:59:00 AM", "9:00:00 AM"
               ), class = "factor"), Value = c(0.56525, 0.8123)), .Names = c("Date", 
                                                                             "Time", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
                                                                             ))
time <- strptime(sample$Time," %H:%M")
qplot(time,sample$Value)+xlab("Time")+ylab("Value")+scale_x_datetime(breaks=date_breaks("1 min"), minor_breaks=date_breaks("10 sec"))
```

I hope it helps.

You have just two points. If you had more points then it would have been easier to plot and visualize better.

Comment: Thanks. The record is comprised of 30 thousand rows.

Comment: @Jdbaba: asking for upvote is frowned upon on SO.. be careful lest you attract wraith of the moderators :)